# Cannot import name DgramSocketTransport using pysnmp in Python

Tags: python, snmp

I have installed pysnmp with:

```
pip install pysnmp
```

This installed version 4.3.2 of pysnmp. When I try to run my script, it's first line is:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\asyncore\dgram\udp6.py", line 9, in module
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram.base import DgramSocketTransport
ImportError: cannot import name DgramSocketTransport
```

If I look into `base.py`, the class `DgramSocketTransport` is there.

What is the problem?

Comment: Today I tested it again and now it's working. Didn't touch nothing. I don't understand why but I won't complain